# Check for a detected face in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, detection, opencv

I want to check if a face has been detected.

I have the variable `face_detect` and when a face is detected I want to turn this variable to `True` however I don't know how to check for a detected face. I tried using `faces.size()` to check if it was greater than zero but it said

> **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'**

So I don't know why that is not working.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import winsound

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

face_detect = False

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `detectMultiScale` should return a list, not a tuple, so I don't understand how you got that error. In any case you can get the length of a list with `len(detectMultiScale)`, and an empty list behaves as `False` so you might not even need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've slightly modified your code to update the `face_detect` variable to True whenever a face is detected.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

face_detect = False

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    
    if len(faces) > 0:
        face_detect = True
    else:
        face_detect = False
    print(face_detect)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If this helped you, please consider marking my question as accepted to give me some credit 